# Get Start and End of the day Epoch second in Java/Android

Tags: android

I am facing issue to get Epoch second of start and end of the current day.
i.e 12 August 00:00:00 and 12 August 23.59.59.

Answer (score 4):

Hope this will be helpful:

```
public long getStartOfDayInMillis() {
   Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
   calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
   calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
   calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
   calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
   return calendar.getTimeInMillis();
 }

public long getEndOfDayInMillis() {
// Add one day's time to the beginning of the day.
// 24 hours * 60 minutes * 60 seconds * 1000 milliseconds = 1 day
return getStartOfDayInMillis() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
}
```

Comment: This is also a possible solution but I have achieved this without calendar object.

Answer (score 3):

Below two functions used to return start of the day and end of the day EPOCH second.

```
 public static Long getStartOfDayEpochSecond() {
    long secondInaDay = 60 * 60 * 24;
    long currentMilliSecond = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
    long startOfTheDayEpoch = currentMilliSecond - (currentMilliSecond %secondInaDay);
   return startOfTheDayEpoch;
}
```

//subtract  endOfTheDayEpoch  with -1 because we use 23.59.59 as end of the day.

```
public static Long getEndOfDayEpochSecond() {
    long startOfTheDayEpoch = getStartOfDayEpochSecond();
    long secondInaDay = 60 * 60 * 24;
    long endOfTheDayEpoch = startOfTheDayEpoch + secondInaDay-1;
    return endOfTheDayEpoch;
}
```

Comment: But why do you return in second. I think very usefull return in millisecond!